# Bounce animation with depth

Tags: android, android-animation

how i can add bounce animation to view which will go down and come up  but it should do this only for one time .

if i set  bounce interpolator with y its bouncing for given duration 
  but i want it for one time only but it should go say 5dp down and up to current view

```
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationY", 0, 50, 0);
    animator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(200);
    animator.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OvershootInterpolator`.

Doc:

> An interpolator where the change flings forward and overshoots the
>   last value then comes back.

You can adjust the tension of the overshoot using the constructor with `tension` parameter:

```
OvershootInterpolator(float tension)
```

> tension: Amount of overshoot. When tension equals 0.0f, there is no
>   overshoot and the interpolator becomes a simple deceleration
>   interpolator.

Default value of `tension` is `2.0f`.

Example using `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
targetView.animate()
    .translationY(50)
    .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator())
    .setDuration(200);
```

using ObjectAnimator:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationY", 0, 50); // pass only start and end values. 
    animator.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(200);
    animator.start();
```

Comment: with ObjectAnimator?

Comment: Yes. `ObjectAnimator` or `ViewPropertyAnimator`. Both should work.

Comment: On a related note, you can pass `View.TRANSLATION_Y` instead of `"translationY"` to the `ObjectAnimator` where the former is the better one as the latter one involves reflection. Or use `ViewPropertyAnimator`. It's [better than ObjectAnimator](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html)

Comment: after this how i can reset view

Comment: `translationY(0)` resets it to original position.

Comment: `targetView.animate().translationY(0)` does animate to original position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152374/discussion-between-andro-and-bob).